# Finding dependencies of a docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, docker, dependencies

I have a docker image and I want to be able to find out how to find out all the dependencies that are being pulled from the internet. I tried looking for an open source program to do this for me but I could not find anything that seems suitable. I am now trying to write my own app in python. Does anyone know where to start?

This is a section of my dockerfile

```
RUN wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/KEYS && \
    wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz.asc && \
    wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz.sha256
```

Comment: What you mean by finding dependencies in docker. You mean the yum or apt-get packages that you install in docker image. FInding dependencies of these packages? Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

1. The https://github.com/wagoodman/dive tool might help you go through previous layers and see what files are in the image.
2. `docker history --no-trunc <yourimage>` will show you what commands were run to build the image.

The combination should let you know what you need.

Answer (score -1):

If those dependencies aren't documented then it's anyone's guess. This is just source and there's never been a requirement to produce a dependency list in machine readable form.

Usually you check the `README.md` or `INSTALL.txt` and hope that explains.

Since you're using Docker, why not look for a Dockerized version of Zookeeper? There's an [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper) which is usually good to go on its own, or you can always look at how that was created by looking through the `Dockerfile` for that build.